# Issue accessing Intercom API

Tags: php, api

I am using the following api library to use intercom api. But for some reason the following code is not working. What I am doing wrong here?

API Library: https://github.com/nubera-ebusiness/intercom-php
Intercom API Doc: http://docs.intercom.io/api

Here is my code:

```
   <?php
      include 'Intercom.php';
      $intercom = new Intercom('dummy-app-id', 'dummy-api-key');
      $users = $intercom->getAllUsers();
      var_dump($users);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Anunay

Comment: What do you mean by, it doesn't work?

Comment: I get NULL as an output fyi

Comment: Have you checked the errors you're getting back? And have you added your own appID and API key in there?

Comment: But when i try to access the following url it works. I don't know what is wrong: https://dummy-app-id:dummy-api-key@api.intercom.io/v1/users/?page=1

Comment: Well we can use the dummy id and key for the test purpose and this is not working either. I tried with my own key and id and same. No friendly errors except NULL. So its hard to debug. I am not sure but is it something with the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);`??

Comment: What about `$intercom->getLastError()`?

Comment: trying that code i get the following message and something related to SSL issue. `Array ( [code] => 60 [message] => SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain )`. How can i solve this?

Comment: It looks like CURL is refusing to connect because the SSL certificate it's using is self-signed (I think). It's not an issue with the software, I don't think, but I don't know enough about SSL to be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you edit that error message into the question and tag it as SSL, you should be able to find someone who can help.

Comment: Anyways, this helps a lot. I will dig down more and post the solution here. Thank you so much for you help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by myself modifying the code library httpCall function appending the code

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`

just above the:

`$response = curl_exec($ch);`.

Cheers

Anunay

Comment: If you have to do this it would indicate you have a problem with your server configuration. I'm not aware of the exact details you need to change, but setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to FALSE opens you up to spoofing attacks.

Comment: I agree but I couldn't find a way out to fix that issue so I fixed that way. I am just not sure what I am doing wrong here :( But thank you for your answer :)